# Sencha grouped grid unnecessary additional row

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, sencha-architect

I have a grouped grid connected with a store. When the data gets loaded there is an additional row at the end of each group. It doesn't appear as an item but just as an unnecessary additional row. Where did this came from and how can I remove it? See screenshot...

[image]

Comment: Can you share some relevant code?

Comment: It's just a grid connected to a store. It is the generated code with Sencha Architect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a summary row turned on to be displayed.